# Sinatra ActiveRecord Model Problems

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

So I'm writing my first Sinatra app, and using ActiveRecord as ORM.

so in my app.rb, I have a

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_uniqueness_of :username
    validates_presence_of :username
end
```

and create a migration and ran rake db:migrate on this

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :email
      t.string :password
      t.string :name
      t.float :rating
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
 end
```

However, when in one of my methods I run

```
post "/create" do
    u = User.new
    u.save
    redirect '/'
end
```

Sinatra crashes on the `User.new` and says
No GET data. on it. I've looked at tutorials and have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I declared the User class before the function so it didn't see the class.